# 'str' object has no attribute 'cpu'

Tags: python, string, object, bert-language-model

With Python 3, I use an sentiment analysis model based on Google BERT that can be trained. The model was working very stably, but for a week in the 'mapping' part of the model; I get an error in the form of 'str' object has no attribute 'cpu' and I couldn't find a solution. Where could the problem come from?

````
def filter(text):
    final_text = ''
    for word in text.split():
        if word.startswith('@'):
            continue
        elif word[-3:] in ['com', 'org']:
            continue
        elif word.startswith('pic') or word.startswith('http') or word.startswith('www'):
            continue
        else:
            final_text += word+' '
    return final_text

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("dbmdz/bert-base-turkish-128k-uncased")
bert = AutoModel.from_pretrained("dbmdz/bert-base-turkish-128k-uncased").to('cuda')

def feature_extraction(text):
    x = tokenizer.encode(filter(text))
    with torch.no_grad():
        x, _ = bert(torch.stack([torch.tensor(x)]).to('cuda'))
        return list(x[0][0].cpu().numpy())

mapping = {'negative':0, 'neutral':1, 'positive':2}
X_train = []
y_train = []
X_test = []
y_test = []
for element in tqdm(train):
    X_train.append(feature_extraction(element['sentence']))
    y_train.append(mapping[element['value']])
for element in tqdm(test):
    X_test.append(feature_extraction(element['sentence']))
    y_test.append(mapping[element['value']])

  0%|          | 0/1070 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-74243ebcdd12> in <module>()
      5 y_test = []
      6 for element in tqdm(train):
----> 7     X_train.append(feature_extraction(element['sentence']))
      8     y_train.append(mapping[element['value']])
      9 for element in tqdm(test):

<ipython-input-5-8e259a97cc89> in feature_extraction(text)
      6     with torch.no_grad():
      7         x, _ = bert(torch.stack([torch.tensor(x)]).to('cuda'))
----> 8         return list(x[0][0].cpu().numpy())

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'cpu'```
````

Comment: `return list(x[0][0].cpu().numpy())` this line is causing error.... Why are you using 'x[0][0].cpu()'?, you can remove `.cpu()`

Comment: Dear @Ashwing Geet D'Sa thanks for the answer. The error was caused by updating the transformers library I used. The problem was resolved when I set the transformers version to 3.0.2.